# Error rendering dynamic content from Jupyter Notebook Dashboard

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bokeh, panel

I'm trying to run a dashboard which is actually a Jupyter notebook. I've created the dashboard using the [panel library](https://panel.holoviz.org/). My dashboard contains some dynamic content. All this worked well on my local machine. Now, I'm trying to do the same on an AWS server. The static content loads fine. But I get this error somehow for the dynamic content:-

[image: failed to load Bokeh session]

> *bokeh.min.js?v=57d29d5936e494351385d736f792154c:550 [bokeh] Failed to load Bokeh session HxjcYn9BmVgnOJsBicuXlx8fEuUQkxViUb7ROVIVGNel:
>   Error: Could not open websocket*

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: The very top error is HTTP 403 Forbidden. I think, your AWS instance is configured incorrectly. No other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by passing the --allow-websocket-origin=myserver_ip:app_port argument while starting it.